# Intersection of 2 complements

Tags: probability

If events A and B are mutually exclusive, what is the probability of the intersection of 
their complement?

I reasoned that

$$P(A^c \cup B^c) = 1 $$
$$ 1 = P(A^c) + P(B^c) - P(A^c \cap B^c) $$
$$ P(A^c \cap B^c) = P(A^c) - P(B^c) - 1$$

However, I also saw in a recent post that

$$P(A^c \cap B^c) = 1 - P(A) - P(B) $$

which is not equal to what I got.

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Check your steps from your second to third line.

Comment: And now note that $P(X)=1-P(X^c)$.

Comment: Also, recheck step 2 -> 3

Comment: Thanks! Algebra typo, I was worried there for a second... :)

Comment: Wohoo, success!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$ P(A^c \cap B^c) = P(A^c) + P(B^c) - 1 $$
$$ P(A^c \cap B^c) = (1 - P(A)) + (1 - P(B)) - 1 $$
$$ P(A^c \cap B^c) = 1 - P(A) - P(B)$$

Comment: How did you get the first result for the intersection of complements?  Thank you